# How to COUNTIFS with one criteria_range but multiple criterion?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am confused on how to countifs with one criteria_range but multiple criterion. I used to do it like this in Excel.

`=COUNTIFS(Critical!H:H,"ACS Media",{Critical!E:E,"Greg Silva","Sharice Payton","Daryl Bond"},Critical!M:M,"Disco/Supplier Status")`

But my formula above doesn't work on Google Sheets. I have multiple names needed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to do **OR** type counts is with a REGEXMATCH(... , "...|...|...").

so something like ...

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(Critical!H:H,Critical!H:H="ACS Media",Critical!M:M="Disco/Supplier Status",REGEXMATCH(Critical!E:E,"Greg Silva|Sharice Payton|Daryl Bond")))
```

Comment: I used the formula you have provided. But it didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: @Jezun if you provide a sample, I'm sure we can get it working.

Comment: This is a sample of what im trying to get.
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHtKxsygTlx-07pCKx5d-L5waZCaK3J-VLez3UFqYhM/edit#gid=359656787]

Comment: try again to access

Comment: it got worse.  now i can't even see view only.

Comment: sorry. try again now

Comment: @Jezun View Only Again.

Comment: @Jezun It is not clear what column you're trying to count, and where you want your answer.  Could you elaborate where on the sheet you're trying to show this count?

Comment: I am trying to count how many rows that has a value of Disco/Supplier Status and On Hold under those people.